# Rotate UIView in place when orientation changes

Tags: uiview, rotation, screen-orientation, ios-autolayout

Briefly, I want to properly use autolayout (and maybe size classes) to get a column of UIViews to rotate in place when the orientation changes. I can get the correct before and after looks (see images) using a UIStackView, but the transition is not what I want: each little image-label combination should rotate individually. I have tried embedding the image-label pair in a wrapper view, setting constraints in various plausible and implausible combinations... going crazy. Would prefer to use IB as much as possible, but willing to go to programmatical if necessary.

It's so easy to visualize this that one thinks it should be comparably easy to implement. I know enough linear algebra to do it all by hand, but really can't I stand on some tall shoulders?

[image: vertical]

[image]